# Simplify a code in R

Tags: r, vector, logical-operators

I have written a code that runs through the columns of a dataframe and returns TRUE if it has a number 1 in any of them, and sends the value to a vector with the same size as a column of the dataframe. I would like to know if there is a way to simplify the code snippet below, since I will have to repeat it for several numbers.

```
n1 <- (tab[, 2]==1|  tab[, 3]==1 | tab[, 4]==1 | tab[, 5]==1 | 
     tab[, 6]==1 | tab[, 7]==1 | tab[, 8]==1 | tab[, 9]==1 |
     tab[, 10]==1 | tab[, 11]==1 | tab[, 12]==1 | tab[, 13]==1 |
     tab[, 14]==1 | tab[, 15]==1 | tab[, 16]==1)
```

Comment: Read up on the apply family of functions. Type `?apply` or `?lapply` in your R terminal, and welcome to the world of R!

Comment: IsraelMotta, do either of the answers provided solve your question? If so, etiquette suggests you "accept" the preferred answer by selecting the checkmark to the left of the specific answer. (If not, please give feedback.) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other comments and answers can work, but I suggest they are encouraging bad behavior when dealing with a `data.frame`. First and foremost is that `apply` and `rowSums` expect a `matrix` as the data, and will happily coerce to such if given a `data.frame`. If any of the `data.frame` columns are `character`, then all columns will be converted to `character`. Some operations may still work as expected (e.g., `== 1` since it will effectively be `== "1"` ... though some rounding errors may cause undesired effects), but anything mathematic will not work.

As an example,

```
n <- 20
set.seed(2)
tab <- data.frame(
  a = as.character(sample(n, replace = FALSE)),
  b1 = sample(5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  b2 = sample(5, size = n, replace = TRUE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
str(tab)
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a : chr  "4" "14" "11" "3" ...
#  $ b1: int  4 2 5 1 2 3 1 2 5 1 ...
#  $ b2: int  5 2 1 1 5 4 5 2 3 5 ...

apply(tab, 1, function(y) any(y == 1))
#  [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
apply(tab, 1, sum)
# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

rowSums(tab == 1)
#  [1] 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
rowSums(tab)
# Error in rowSums(tab) : 'x' must be numeric
```

There are some easy ways to deal with this. Given your example, it appears that columns `2:16` are numeric and the ones you are concerned about. If that's the case, then you can safely use either one of:

```
rowSums(tab[,2:16] == 1)                      # Frank's comment
apply(tab[,2:16], 1, function(y) any(y == 1)) # suggested by You-leee's answer
```

(the former being fairly specific, the latter can be extended to other functionality). If there's only one non-`numeric`, once can always do

```
rowSums(tab[,-1,drop=FALSE] == 1)
apply(tab[,-1,drop=FALSE], 1, function(y) any(y == 1))
```

A third technique is to determine at run time which columns to choose:

```
isnum <- sapply(tab, is.numeric)
Reduce(`|`, lapply(tab[isnum], function(y) any(y == 1)))
```

This was a little more complex, because the return from `lapply` is a `list`, but it still works fine. Realize that the use of `isnum` could be based on column names as well, using something like `grepl`. This method is fairly robust, too, in that it does not error if none of the columns match.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. This solution worked perfectly, due to being a dataframe i think it is the most secure solution.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is the following: you search for == 1 numbers in the dataframe and then Reduce the rows of that with the `|` operator:

```
tab <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 2:11)

apply(tab == 1, 1, function(x) {
  Reduce("|", x)
})
```

For this example it will give you the ouput of:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or one even simpler solution is:

```
apply(tab, 1, function(x) {
  any(x == 1)
})
```

Comment: Or `rowSums(tab == 1) > 0`

Comment: It's sloppy and error-prone to use `apply` or `rowSums` with a `data.frame`; if you are confident that it is all numbers, then there is little reason for it to *not* be a `matrix`, for which those functions work perfectly. The moment you mistakenly have a non-`numeric` in your data, both functions break and/or change behavior. (In this trivial case, simple `==` does not necessarily break, but my premise stands.)